# How can I use html div and css style with C# window application?

Tags: c#, html

how can i use html div and css style in my c# window application? i want to show this data in an html table. 
Thanks in advance

```
while (reader.Read())
{
            string fname = (string)reader["std_name"];
            string lname = (string)reader["f_name"];
            string age = (string)reader["age"].ToString();

            MessageBox.Show(fname+", "+lname+", "+age);
}
```

Comment: If this is a WinForms application, you can't embed HTML or CSS directly into the interface. You could use a web browser control to render your markup.

Comment: which language is best for styling in C# window application as css is used in web?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand the question. If you're asking what .NET framework is best suited for using HTML and associated markup for presentation, I would say MVC or web forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think there is no method to add css in wonfor as you can add in html. however you can add css like tags in wpf app.

Answer (score 0):

you must create a html file by your app
this code create a html file and read information from access file 
then inject the informayino into html file:

```js
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace pomp_benzin
{
    class class_print
    {
        public void print_to_html_file(string str_sql,int count_field,string[] headers)
        {
            //خط زير تنها كانكشن استرينگ را ميخواند كه ميتوان ان را نيز به صورت دستي نوشت
            OleDbConnection con=new OleDbConnection(vars.con_str);
            OleDbCommand cmd=new OleDbCommand(str_sql,con);
            con.Open();
            OleDbDataReader rd=cmd.ExecuteReader();
            TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(Application.StartupPath + "\\a.html", false, Encoding.UTF8);
            tw.WriteLine("<table dir='rtl' border='1' style='width:100%;border-style:solid'>");
            //ساخت هدر هر ستون در جدول با توجه به هدر هاي ارسال شده از طرثق آرايه
            tw.WriteLine("<tr>");
            for (int i = 0; i < headers.Length; i++)
            {
                tw.WriteLine("<td style='background-color: #CCCCCC;border-style:solid'>");
                tw.WriteLine(headers[i]);
                tw.WriteLine("</td>");
            }

            while(rd.Read())
            {
                tw.WriteLine("<tr>");
                for (int cel = 0; cel < count_field; cel++)
                {
                    tw.WriteLine("<td style='border-style:solid'>");
                    //محتويات يك فيلد از جدول مربوطه
                    tw.WriteLine(rd.GetValue(cel).ToString());
                    //محتويات يك فيلد از جدول مربوطه
                    tw.WriteLine("</td>");
                }
                tw.WriteLine("</tr>");
            }


            tw.WriteLine(" </table>");
            con.Close();
            tw.Close();
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Application.StartupPath + "\\a.html");
        }
    }
}
```

then you must run a.html by:
    system.diagnostic.process.start("a.html");